# VBA, Resizing table is shifting data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code to resize my table after I add data to it weekly.

```
Sub ResizeListDyn()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion
End Sub
```

Currently the data is like so, with 12-Dec-2018 being in the table. I add the next two weeks data and try to resize the table automatically.

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 12-Dec-2018 | -71700079.84 | -65611884.73 | -1794788.38 |
| 19-Dec-2018 | -82238011.30 | -74725620.20 | -1558074.81 |
| 26-Dec-2018 | -59385932.41 | -54947256.94 | -1811642.55 |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I end up with data like this after running the code:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 19-Dec-2018 | -82238011.30 | -74725620.20 | -1558074.81 |
| 26-Dec-2018 | -59385932.41 | -54947256.94 | -1811642.55 |
| 12-Dec-2018 | -71700079.84 | -65611884.73 | -1794788.38 |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

As you can see 12-Dec-2018 data gets shifted to last row.  But they are all in the table now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by resizing. If you mean you want to refer to the table's entire `databodyrange` including the rows you've just added, assuming you added via `ListRows.Add` or just wrote the data immediately next to/below the table, the table should automatically expand to include the new rows, no? Meaning just access the `ListObject`'s `Range` (includes headers I think) or `DataBodyRange` (without headers)

Comment: The table does expand automatically for the first row. Then when I do another week , ie dec 19, it is not automatically expanding . It only works for the first row...sigh. So I need to resize right?

Comment: How are you adding the data? Manually or through some code? In my experience, the table always expands when you put data immediately next to it (irrespective of whether it's the first, second, third, etc. time that you're adding data.), or for example if you write an array to `databodyrange` that exceeds the table's current dimensions.

Comment: through some code.  I use a `lastrow` code to get the last row then add some formulas to the last row of the table. Doesnt seem to append to the table.

Comment: if you're inserting formulas, your formula may need to be the same for the entire column (i.e. calculated columns) in order for Excel to intuit how to autoexpand the table range. Are the formulas in the `12 Dec` row different to the formulas in the new rows you're adding? Also, strangely enough the reference for ListObject.Resize says "No cells are inserted or moved."

Comment: No, the formulas are the same as 12 Dec. I just re run the code to get results of the next week. Not sure what to do from here.